# Extjs HtmlEditor - Numbered list and bullet list

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, html-editor

I try to working with HTMLEditor in **http://jsfiddle.net/WEEU3/**

But when i chose Numbered list or Bullet list to typing then i press enter keyboard. That like
[image]

I think that like

```
1. first
2. second
3. third
```

And when i focus in **third**. I press to un-numbered. I think that like

```
    1. first
    2. second
third
```

But all word will be un-numbered
How to fix that. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug with htmleditor on 4.1.1.  Also, you should NOT be using new to create the ExtJS objects.  This will cause other ExtJS problems.

Upgrading to 4.2.x will fix your problem with the htmleditor.

Your code should be better formatted.  You should also be using proper ExtJS methods to get items i.e. :

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {  // should be using Ext.create(), not new
    title: 'HTML Editor',
    width: 500,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'htmleditor',
        name: 'editor',
        enableColors: true,
        enableAlignments: false,
        enableLists: true,
        enableSourceEdit: false,
        anchor: '100%'
    }],
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Get HTML',
            handler: function(btn) {
                // example of getting all form values
                console.log(btn.up('form').getForm().getValues()); 

                // proper example of getting by component
                alert(btn.up('form').down('htmleditor').getValue());
            }
        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Using `new` is perfectly acceptable, and even preferred for performance. Since 4.1, ExtJS classes all use `new` internally rather than `Ext.create()` for precisely that reason.

Comment: Talking about propper Ext methods to fetch components and then using getCmp is even worse...

Comment: Yes, you should really use .up(), .down(), .prev(), etc.

Comment: @sra: Per comment fixed.

Comment: If you're using dynamic class loading then you must use Ext.create(). If you're using new, you better know if any required classes have already been loaded.

Comment: That's not working in chrome. the problem like my above picture :(

Comment: Tested at 4.2.0, Chrome 28.0.1500.72 m, works fine. Check your browser plugins.

Comment: But i using Extjs 4.1.1 :(, have anyway to make my code work :(?

Comment: @trungkien you'd probably have to submit a bug to Sencha if one hasn't already been submitted.  Also, you might want to check the Sencha forums as someone might have a hot fix for you to use.

Comment: i just find here is link but i can't use that to make my code working (that using 3.2.1 ...) http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?112881-CLOSED-HtmlEditor-Numbered-List-under-MSIE and http://joekuan.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/extjs-htmleditors-broken-ordered-and-unordered-list-when-hitting-return/